# How many people, on average, floss on a regular basis?

Tags: dentistry, oral-health, statistics, gingivitis, floss-flossing

**How many people, on average, floss on a regular basis?**

I feel like I'm the only person who doesn't floss on a regular basis according to my dentist, but do we know the statistics of how many people actually floss.

I know it's important, but I forget to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this page, http://sunvalleypediatricdentistry.com/statistics-brushing-flossing-oral-health/ 50% of Americans floss daily, 31% floss less regularly, and 18% do not floss at all.